# Issue with UserControl and KeyBinding (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window with a ContentControl, where I show my usercontrol. Each usercontrol has its KeyBindings. The problem is that when a usercontrol loses focus, the keybinding not working. If I click anywhere in the window outside the usercontrol, I not have access to the keybinding. I can use global keybindings, but each is of a specific usercontrol? I found some solutions, but do not serve me. Thx!

Comment: How do you expect it to work? If there are multiple user controls with different keybindings, what should happen when the user control does not have focus? Which keybindings should be active?

Comment: Each Usercontrol has one or more KeyBinding but none are not repeated. Ideally, it would only activate the corresponding keybinding to usercontrol I'm showing. I need that although the usercontrol not have the focus, the keybinding work.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do:

1. Create new class that contains commands. Each command represents action you want to do inside user control

   ```
   public static class CustomCommands
   {
       public static readonly RoutedUICommand SettingsCommand = new RoutedUICommand
           (
                   "SettingsCommand",
                   "SettingsCommand",
                   typeof(CustomCommands),
                   new InputGestureCollection()
                           {

                           }
           );
   }
   ```
2. In your user control subscrube this command:

In XAML:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommands.SettingsCommand" Executed="OnSettingsExecuted"></CommandBinding>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

Or in code-behind:

```
CustomCommands.SettingsCommand.Executed += (s, e) => { };
```

3. In your Window bind keys to commands:

   ```
   <Window.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Control" Command="local:CustomCommands.SettingsCommand" />
   </Window.InputBindings>
   ```

So, you will have window-scale key bindings that will be accepted when the window is active.

Hope, it helps